# Why doesn't this PHP code (comet) work?

Tags: php, comet

```
set_time_limit(0);

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
flush();

while($i < 10)
{
    sleep(1);
    $i++;
    echo $i;
    flush();
}
```

Why doesn't my code print out 1, then wait and print 2 then wait and print 3. Instead, it just waits 10 seconds and prints out 12345678910 all at once?

Is there a way to print it in chunks as I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely because of [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).  Try adding this at the top of the file to close all the open buffers:

```
while(ob_get_level() > 0) {
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

You can also add `ob_flush()` after the `flush()` command in your code:

```
$i++;
echo $i;
flush();
ob_flush();
```

(Note that you should only have to do one of them, not both, but try it)...

Comment: while(ob_get_level() > 0) {
    ob_end_flush();
}
set_time_limit(0);

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
flush();

while($i < 10)
{
 sleep(1);
 
 $i++;
 echo $i;
 flush();
 ob_flush();
}

is what I've tried now but it still doesn't work

Comment: What browser are you using (I know Chrome has a buffer before it'll render)?  You could try opening the page in `telnet` to see if it's a problem with the browser or the server...

Comment: I'm using Chrome, I just tried it in Safari and it's not working either - telnet? I'm not sure how to do that but the URL is http://develop.davzy.com/forum/test.php if you're able to.

Comment: @user309641: It works quite fine for me in Firefox.  It must be that both Chrome and Safari (since they are both webkit browsers) require a buffer to fill prior to rendering.  But it works fine for me here, so your server-side code is running fine (now it's a browser issue)...

Comment: Ah blast! I wanted to do a small comet script using the iframe method on the client, but is there any way I can do that on webkit now?

Comment: @user309641: Check out [this link](http://blog.samshull.com/2010/10/ajax-push-in-ios-safari-and-chrome-with.html) for an alternative implementation...

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be you need some junk data to start the streaming in some webbrowsers.

A quote from this [link](http://www.shanison.com/?p=237)

> Firstly, the server must push some
>   junk data (around 2k) to the browser
>   before you push the real data. So just
>   write out some javascript comments to
>   the browsers first.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {   
  write.print("<!——————————————–this is junk—————–!>"); 
}
```